# Match partial date in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a way to match a date, with the one related to records on my db.

I know how to match strings with the LIKE operator, but it doesn't work for dates; unless I search just for a number (say all records at 10, all records from the 21st and so on). As soon as I put minutes for example, the search with LIKE return no records.

How do you actually search for partial date? My objective is to find all records newer than a partial date; in the current day.

```
select * from CLIENTS where CLOSING like '%12:30%'
```

This won't match anything; but if I use just 12 or 30, it works....although it is not doing what I want.

Do I have to convert date in strings? I get a partial date from another process, and I would like to match all the records newer than the partial date.

Comment: are you looking particularly for some date parts? it will help if you post your dataset and expected resultset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from CLIENTS where 
TO_CHAR(CLOSING , 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss') like '%12:30%'
```

or

```
select * from CLIENTS where 
TO_CHAR(CLOSING , 'hh24:mi') = '12:30'
```

Comment: Perfect! so I have to set the format too, and convert to char. I assume that this is what the TO_CHAR function does. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, it is useful; I can't mark it as solution until the cooldown period expire. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want loans more recent than today at 12:30pm, you are best served to use date arithmetic rather than relying on string conversion

```
SELECT *
  FROM clients
 WHERE closing >= trunc(sysdate) + interval '12' hour + interval '30' minute;
```

or

```
SELECT *
  FROM clients
 WHERE closing >= trunc(sysdate) + 12.5/24
```

Here, `trunc(sysdate)` returns today at midnight.  Then you can either add a fractional number of days (1/24 adds one hour so 12.5/24 takes you to 12:30pm) or you can add one or more intervals (you could use `to_dsinterval` as well to create the interval).